# I can't see the newly added toolbar buttons I added to CKEditor

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I have added some new buttons from the toolbar configuration onto the BasicHTML profile of CKEditor
(admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html)
I've added the standard text alignment buttons and also the color button which was supplied by the module I installed (details below)

However, when I try and use the editor (whether in paragraphs, or the standard wysiwyg supplied by Drupal), the new buttons don't appear. I've cleared caches etc.

Does anyone know what I'm missing ?

I am using:

- Drupal 8
- CKEditor 8.85
- CKEditor ColorButton 8.x-1.2

I've installed the color button module and uploaded the 2 libraries (colorbutton & panelbutton)

Comment: Anything in `/admin/reports/status` or `/admin/reports/dblog` ?

Comment: Can't see anything pertaining to CKEditor or ColorButton or PanelButton in there

Comment: Are you limiting html tags? Did you allow the appropriate tags/properties needed by the new buttons?

Comment: This is so close to being the correct answer!   When I use the text justification control, it adds a class to the <p> element, so in the "Allowed HTML tags" area I added <p class=""> and those buttons now appear (and work!)  However, the color button wants to add the colour by means of "<span style="color:#123xyz">"  So... I added <span style=""> to the Allowed HTML tags. Upon save, this got changed to <span style> but even though the button is shown, it doesn't save the style attribute that is added when editing